# help me to find the Line Integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find  [image]
 for  [image]
on the curve counterclockwise around the unit circle C starting at the point (1,0).

I dont know the way to do that I tried many ways but I still could not get the right answer

Comment: I've tried to do it like the normal line integral but I just could not get the right answer, integral F.dl

Comment: *Hint:*   Use [Green's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_theorem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two possible methods you can use. Either you can use Green's Theorem (easy) or evaluate the line integral (harder). I'll do the line integral first:

First off, parametrise the unit circle by letting $\mathbf r = (\cos t ,\sin t )$,    $t \in [0, 2 \pi)$. Then $\mathbf r '= (-\sin t, \cos t)$ and using the formula

$$\oint_C \mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf r = \int \mathbf F(\mathbf r(t)) \cdot \mathbf r ' (t) dt$$

We obtain:

$$I = \oint_C \mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf r = \int_0^{2\pi} (6\sin t, \sin(\sin t))\cdot(-\sin t, \cos t) dt $$

$$=\int_0^{2\pi} -6\sin^2 t + \cos t \cdot \sin (\sin t) dt$$

The first half of this integral is easy enough to evaluate, the second can be evaluated by noticing $\frac{d}{dt} \cos(\sin t) = -\cos t \cdot \sin (\sin t)$. Thus the value of the integral is $I=-6\pi$.

Now by Green's Theorem. Green's Theorem tells us that:

$$I = \oint_C \mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf r = \iint_D \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y} dxdy$$

Since $\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x} = 0$, and $\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y} = 6$, the result follows from the fact that the area of the unit circle is $\pi$.